# I have included google analytics with user id in my android app.I want to get the full list of user ids that has used my app

Tags: android, google-analytics

Here is the code to include userId......

```
tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext)
                         .newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);

if (isLogin) {
    tracker.set("&uid", UserPreferences.getInstance().getuserName());
}
```

Comment: That feature's not available to be bulk, the closest option is to use the User Explorer Report or include the User Id as a Custom Dimension and download that report, but the second option needs the care of the numbers of elements to be sent to the platform to avoid high cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ROHITLIEN did you get user id data this way?  I followed this technique and the user id data did not show up in my property.